# How to work with two different Xamarin version on VS 2013 and VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2015

I just install the latest Visual Studio 2015, which has also installed the latest Xamarin version. But I have a project with older Xamarin version on Visual Studio 2013 and I would like to keep it, without updating to latest Xamarin. How can I use the older Xamarin version on Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: work with isolated VMs. In 1 you can use VS2013 with the older version and 1 with VS2015 and the newer version.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use two different versions of Xamarin at the same time. You will either have to install/reinstall or use a VM or different machine.

Any particular reason you don't want to upgrade to the latest Xamarin in 2013? You could just re-install the Xamarin that you want in 2013 in 2015 and just use that older version in both.